# How to make RelativeLayout.XConstraint platform specific

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Iam trying for relative layout in xamarin.forms,its working good in android but iam not getting correct alignment with the same values in iOS,is there any way to give platform specifications for relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"  HeightRequest="112.5">
    <Image Source="close.png" Scale="0.3" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.25}">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CancelPopUpCommand}"/>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add screen shot of your issue "not getting correct alignment" for more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can add platform dependent resources and bind your factor to it:

```
<RelativeLayout Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"  HeightRequest="112.5">
    <RelativeLayout.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="0.30" Android="0.25" x:Key="XFactor" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </RelativeLayout.Resources>
    <Image Source="close.png" Scale="0.3" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor={StaticResource XFactor}}">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CancelPopUpCommand}"/>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57281/how-can-i-make-platform-specific-relativelayout-xconstraint-in-xaml

Comment: Thanks for the replay @Dennis Schroer,i have tried it but not getting the thing what iam lookng for,i solved it by following :https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2016/12/20/setting-relativelayout-constraintexpressions-from-xaml-styles-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: That's confusing because that's pretty much the same but in a different way as in my answer, but glad you got it working.